# Sales Grid - Adding country appears blank

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, order-grid

I am trying to **add Shipping Country to the sales order grid**.

I have tried a lot of code snippets I found on stack but none of them seem to work!

These were for older Magento and I am running 1.9.2.2 so maybe this is why?

I have even tried adding other fields as a base such a postcode as below with no luck...

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order_address', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id',array('postcode'));
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

...

$this->addColumn('postcode', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Postcode'),
    'index' => 'postcode',
));
```

Is there anything special in 1.9.2.2 that would mean these methods I have tried would not work?

EDIT: Still stuck on this!!!

EDIT: Full code below:

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Adminhtml
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

/**
 * Adminhtml sales orders grid
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_Adminhtml
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Splitpixel_OrderGrid_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('sales_order_grid');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve collection class
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getCollectionClass()
    {
        return 'sales/order_grid_collection';
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
      $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
      $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('order' => Mage::getModel('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order_address')),
      'address.parent_id=main_table.entity_id',array('postcode' => 'postcode','country_id'=>'country_id'))
      ->where("address.address_type =  'billing'");
      $this->setCollection($collection);
      return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {

        $this->addColumn('real_order_id', array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order #'),
            'width' => '80px',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'index' => 'increment_id',
        ));

        if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
            $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased From (Store)'),
                'index'     => 'store_id',
                'type'      => 'store',
                'store_view'=> true,
                'display_deleted' => true,
            ));
        }

        $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'),
            'index' => 'created_at',
            'type' => 'datetime',
            'width' => '100px',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('billing_name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bill to Name'),
            'index' => 'billing_name',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('shipping_name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Ship to Name'),
            'index' => 'shipping_name',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('base_grand_total', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Base)'),
            'index' => 'base_grand_total',
            'type'  => 'currency',
            'currency' => 'base_currency_code',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('grand_total', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Purchased)'),
            'index' => 'grand_total',
            'type'  => 'currency',
            'currency' => 'order_currency_code',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('status', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Status'),
            'index' => 'status',
            'type'  => 'options',
            'width' => '70px',
            'options' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses(),
        ));

        $this->addColumn('postcode', array(
          'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Post code'),
          'align'     =>'left',
          'width'     => '50px',
          'index'     => 'postcode',
          'filter_index' => 'address.postcode'
        ));
         $this->addColumn('country_id', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Country '),
            'index' => 'country_id',
            'type'=> 'options',
            'options'=>$this->getAllCountry(),
            'filter_index' => 'address.country_id',
        ));

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
            $this->addColumn('action',
                array(
                    'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Action'),
                    'width'     => '50px',
                    'type'      => 'action',
                    'getter'     => 'getId',
                    'actions'   => array(
                        array(
                            'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('View'),
                            'url'     => array('base'=>'*/sales_order/view'),
                            'field'   => 'order_id',
                            'data-column' => 'action',
                        )
                    ),
                    'filter'    => false,
                    'sortable'  => false,
                    'index'     => 'stores',
                    'is_system' => true,
            ));
        }
        $this->addRssList('rss/order/new', Mage::helper('sales')->__('New Order RSS'));

        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Excel XML'));

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    public function getAllCountry(){

    $options = Mage::getResourceModel('directory/country_collection')->load()->toOptionArray();
    $countries = array();
    foreach($options as $options){
     $countries[$options['value']]=$options['label'];
    }
    return $countries;
    }

    const XPATH_CONFIG_SETTINGS_IS_ACTIVE       = '../community/orders2csv/settings/is_active';

    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {

      parent::_prepareMassaction();

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('auit_pdfdocs_order_all', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Orders'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('auit_pdf/order/printall'),
        ));

        return $this;

      parent::_prepareMassaction();
    if (Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XPATH_CONFIG_SETTINGS_IS_ACTIVE)) {

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('orders2csv', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Orders2CSV'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order_orders2csv/makecsv'),
        ));
    }

        $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('order_ids');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setUseSelectAll(false);

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/cancel')) {
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('cancel_order', array(
                 'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Cancel'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massCancel'),
            ));
        }

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/hold')) {
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('hold_order', array(
                 'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Hold'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massHold'),
            ));
        }

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/unhold')) {
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('unhold_order', array(
                 'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Unhold'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massUnhold'),
            ));
        }

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfinvoices_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Invoices'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfinvoices'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfshipments_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Packingslips'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfshipments'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfcreditmemos_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Credit Memos'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfcreditmemos'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfdocs_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print All'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfdocs'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('print_shipping_label', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Shipping Labels'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order_shipment/massPrintShippingLabel'),
        ));

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
            return $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $row->getId()));
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have added the data to the *_prepareCollection* method have you also added the column to the *_prepareColumns* method?

Here's a good guide from Inchoo 
http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-from-scratch/

Answer (score 1):

@Weaves81 say,right.

For *add country and Postcode*,you need  to *`properly add fields`* and *join* table *`sales_flat_address`*   to collection in ***respectively  functions***

Whenever,Magento create `an order` then `two rows insert` in *`sales_flat_order_address`* order for that order.***`One is for billing address and another is for shipping`***.

So,this `$collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order_address', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id',array('postcode'));`should create issue.

For prevent this,you need to add  another condition like **`->where("address.address_type =  'billing'")`**, that will prevent to call of  ***duplicated rows*** .

Also,you can use `shipping` **`->where("address.address_type =  'shipping'")`**,if you want to get **`country,postcode`** etc detail from shipping address.

Another thing,`country_id` only give us `country_id` not *country name* that need to make  country_id field as drop field and getting **`country name`**,you  *`should call function which is give us country  name`*.

```
public function getAllCountry(){

$options = Mage::getResourceModel('directory/country_collection')->load()->toOptionArray(); 
$countries = array(); 
foreach($options as $options){
 $countries[$options['value']]=$options['label']; 
} 
return $countries;
}
```

### Rewrite class then add columns to show country id:

```
<?php
class Devamitbera_AdvanceSalesGrid_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid{
  protected function _prepareColumns()
    {

        parent::_prepareColumns();
        $this->addColumn('postcode', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Post code'),
            'index' => 'postcode',
        ));
         $this->addColumn('country_id', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Country '),
            'index' => 'country_id',
            'type'=> 'options',
            'options'=>$this->getAllCountry(),      
           'filter_index' => 'address.country_id',
        ));



        return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareColumns();

    }
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('address' => Mage::getModel('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order_address')), 
        'address.parent_id=main_table.entity_id',array('postcode' => 'postcode','country_id'=>'country_id'))
        ->where("address.address_type =  'billing'");
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();
    }



    public function getAllCountry(){

    $options = Mage::getResourceModel('directory/country_collection')->load()->toOptionArray(); 
    $countries = array(); 
    foreach($options as $options){
     $countries[$options['value']]=$options['label']; 
    } 
    return $countries;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, I used your code and it still appears blank I have added my full code in the post.

Comment: issue is resolved.Just need change return class of _prepareCollection to ` return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();`

Comment: I then get an error code updated above: a:5:{i:0;s:210:"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'address.address_type' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table` WHERE (address.address_type =  'billing')";i:1;s:6407:"

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar requirement some time back, where I need to add customer email and shipping region to the sales order grid. 
For achieving the requirement I have rewritten class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid` as below in my custom module.

```
class Custom_OrderGrid_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid {

    protected function _getCollectionClass() {
        return 'sales/order_collection';
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection() {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());

        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfog' => 'sales_flat_order_grid'), 'main_table.entity_id = sfog.entity_id', array('sfog.shipping_name', 'sfog.billing_name'));

        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfo' => 'sales_flat_order'), 'sfo.entity_id=main_table.entity_id', array('sfo.customer_email', 'sfo.increment_id', 'sfo.store_id', 'sfo.created_at', 'sfo.status', 'sfo.base_grand_total', 'sfo.grand_total'));

        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfoa' => 'sales_flat_order_address'), 'main_table.entity_id = sfoa.parent_id AND sfoa.address_type="shipping"', array('sfoa.region'));

        $this->setCollection($collection);

        return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns() {

        $this->addColumn('real_order_id', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order #'),
            'width' => '80px',
            'type' => 'text',
            'index' => 'increment_id',
            'filter_index' => 'sfo.increment_id'
        ));

        if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
            $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased From (Store)'),
                'index' => 'store_id',
                'type' => 'store',
                'store_view' => true,
                'display_deleted' => true,
                'filter_index' => 'sfo.store_id'
            ));
        }

        $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'),
            'index' => 'created_at',
            'type' => 'datetime',
            'width' => '100px',
            'filter_index' => 'sfo.created_at'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('billing_name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bill to Name'),
            'index' => 'billing_name',
            'filter_index' => 'sfog.billing_name'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('shipping_name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Ship to Name'),
            'index' => 'shipping_name',
            'filter_index' => 'sfog.shipping_name'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('customer_email', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Customer Email'),
            'index' => 'customer_email',
            'filter_index' => 'sfo.customer_email',
            'width' => '50px',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('region', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping State'),
            'index' => 'region',
            'filter_index' => 'sfoa.region',
            'width' => '50px',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('base_grand_total', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Base)'),
            'index' => 'base_grand_total',
            'type' => 'currency',
            'currency' => 'base_currency_code',
            'filter_index' => 'sfo.base_grand_total'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('grand_total', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Purchased)'),
            'index' => 'grand_total',
            'type' => 'currency',
            'currency' => 'order_currency_code',
            'filter_index' => 'sfo.grand_total'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('status', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Status'),
            'index' => 'status',
            'type' => 'options',
            'width' => '70px',
            'filter_index' => 'sfo.status',
            'options' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses(),
        ));

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
            $this->addColumn('action', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Action'),
                'width' => '50px',
                'type' => 'action',
                'getter' => 'getId',
                'actions' => array(
                    array(
                        'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('View'),
                        'url' => array('base' => '*/sales_order/view'),
                        'field' => 'order_id'
                    )
                ),
                'filter' => false,
                'sortable' => false,
                'index' => 'stores',
                'is_system' => true,
            ));
        }
        $this->addRssList('rss/order/new', Mage::helper('sales')->__('New Order RSS'));

        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Excel XML'));

        return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareColumns();
    }

}
```

I hope this will help you. 
You can check this code and compare it with yours and try to do modification to resolve your error.